# How to create a model for this relationship in Laravel 5?

Tags: laravel, model, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have the following schema:

```
Modules
=======
id: PK
current_revision: FK to Revisions.Id, nullable

Revisions
=========
id: PK
```

The `current_revision` field either references to a single revision id or set to null.

My question is how do I properly model this relationship in Laravel.

Here's how I did it so far:

```
class Module extends Model
{
    public function current_revision()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Revision::class, 'current_revision');
    }

}
```

However, I did not do the inverse in the `revision` model, as there can be revisions with no `module` assigned to it.

Is this the correct way to model this relationship?

Also why does the following `$module->current_revision` not output a collection of revisions? Instead it outputs the contents of the field.

However it's worth mentioning the following works fine: `$module->current_revision()->getResults()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**About your current relationship:**

Since current_revision points to only one record on the revisions table, you can expect your relationship to return a single Revision model, and not a collection.

The reason you are getting the contents of the field and not the model, is that your field and relationship share the same name. So, when you ask for `$model->current_revision`, Laravel gives you the value of that field on the database.

The easiest way to solve this would be to rename either the database column or the relationship name. I usually append _id to foreign key columns so that is never a problem.

**About the inverse relationship:**

You can define the relationship the same way, even though the column is nullable. If there aren't any modules related to one revision, `$revision->module` (for example) will just return null.

Comment: Thanks a lot. For some reason I thought the Laravel reads the method name or something. Thanks for clearing the confusion!